# Dark flow installation visual studio dependency error

Tags: python, c++, darkflow

I am trying to install the darkflow libraries from the repository: https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow

Unfortunately when entering either

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

or

```
pip install -e .
```

results in the following error:

```
running build_ext
building 'darkflow.cython_utils.nms' extension
     error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

I have installed visual studios 2017 and edited my environment variables to include

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools
```

However I continue to get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: 14.0 is Visual Studio 2015. 14.1 is Visual Studio 2017. What you need is VS 2015.

Comment: Technically, VC++ 14.0 is Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. Also, try to invoke pip from "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017"

Comment: @Rosme so should I download and install vS 2015? Where do i get that from?

Comment: You could try what @R2RT said. Alternatively, [Microsoft website](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/) contains what you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

The fix:
You need to download "Microsoft Build Tools 2015 Update 3"
from

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/

After installation

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually install a compiler, after installing Tools 2017:
 1. Re-open the installer
 2. Modify your solution (eg. Community 2017)
 3. Search for the compiler you need (eg. Tool kit VC++ 2015.3 v140 for desktop (x86, x64))
 4. Press modify button